# M2Crypto RSA.gen_key - feed a password from Python code

Tags: m2crypto

RSA.gen_key function always asks for password when it's used to generate keys. Is there a way to feed it the password from the python code instead of typing it manually?

Answer (score 3):

The only time it asks for a password is if you try to save a key and you choose to use a cipher. Just pass "cipher=None" as an argument.

For example:

```
key=RSA.gen_key(2048, 65537)
key.save_pem('./privkey',cipher=None)
```

But as Heikki said, key generation requires no password. Only saving if you choose to use encryption.

Answer (score 1):

It does not ask for passwords as far as I know:

```
In [1]: from M2Crypto import RSA

In [2]: r=RSA.gen_key(1024, 65537)
..++++++
.......................................++++++

In [3]:
```

If you don't like that output, you can provide a custom callback function. See [documentation](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.RSA-module.html#gen_key) and [tests](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/test_rsa.py).

If you mean that it asks for passphrase when calling [`save_pem()`](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.RSA.RSA-class.html#save_pem) method, you are right: the default will ask for password. But again, you can provide your own callback that provides the password programmatically.